# Weblogic - Securing the web service URL by grant access to specific IPs

Tags: web-services, security, weblogic11g

I wanna to grant access to specific IPs to access the web service which deployed with EAR application on Weblogic.

I know one of the solution for this issue is restricting access to WS URL, by set up security constraints on a web resource collection on webservices.xml file. But I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is done on firewall level, rather than application server level.

Comment: Surely I know that dude, there is some security-constraint elements in webservice.xml file which I should know how to edit it .